# for each loop in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to do one transformation using XSLT. As per below sample, there are multiple EmpRecord available and each EmpRecord contains EmpDept and Profile of available employees under that Department.

**XML:**

```
<Employee>
    <EmpRecord>
        <EmpDept>Accounting</EmpDept>
        <EmpData>
            <Name>Joy</Name>
            <Age>32</Age>
        </EmpData>
    </EmpRecord>
    <EmpRecord>
        <EmpDept>Finance</EmpDept>
    </EmpRecord>
    <EmpRecord>
        <EmpDept>IT</EmpDept>
        <EmpData>
            <Name>Sam</Name>
            <Age>27</Age>
        </EmpData>
        <EmpData>
            <Name>John</Name>
            <Age>25</Age>
        </EmpData>
        <EmpData>
            <Name>Ricky</Name>
            <Age>31</Age>
        </EmpData>
    </EmpRecord>
</Employee>
```

**Expected Output :**

```
<Employee>
    <EmpRecord>
        <Department>Accounting</Department>
        <EmpData>
            <EmpName>Joy</EmpName>
            <Age>32</Age>
        </EmpData>
    </EmpRecord>
    <EmpRecord>
        <Department>IT</Department>
        <EmpData>
            <EmpName>Sam</EmpName>
            <Age>27</Age>
        </EmpData>
        <EmpData>
            <EmpName>John</EmpName>
            <Age>25</Age>
        </EmpData>
        <EmpData>
            <EmpName>Ricky</EmpName>
            <Age>31</Age>
        </EmpData>
    </EmpRecord>
</Employee>
```

I am able to get all available EmpData but unable to fetch EmpDept.

**XSLT used:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<Employee>
<xsl:for-each select="/Employee/EmpRecord/EmpData">
<Department><xsl:value-of select="./EmpDept"/></Department>
<EmpData>
<EmpName><xsl:value-of select="./Name"/></EmpName>
<Age><xsl:value-of select="./Age"/></Age>
</EmpData>
</xsl:for-each>
</Employee>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So I want only those EmpDept which has at least one employee available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/Employee">
    <Employee>
        <xsl:for-each select="EmpRecord[EmpData]">
            <EmpRecord>
                <Department>
                    <xsl:value-of select="EmpDept"/>
                </Department>
                <xsl:for-each select="EmpData">
                    <EmpData>
                        <EmpName>
                            <xsl:value-of select="Name"/>
                        </EmpName>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="Age"/>
                    </EmpData>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </EmpRecord>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Employee>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Or, if you prefer:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="EmpRecord[not(EmpData)]"/>

<xsl:template match="EmpDept">
    <Department>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </Department>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Name">
    <EmpName>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </EmpName>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you actually want to do is: copy everything from source to target xml, aside from `EmpRecord` not containing any `EmpData`. Right? Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" method="xml" version="1.0" indent="yes"/>
    <!-- identity template -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- specific part -->
    <xsl:template match="EmpRecord[not(EmpData)]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

"identity template" copies everything, "specific part" deletes the unwanted elements.

Comment: Sorry if my expected output is misleading, actually I don't want to copy exactly. There is tag and structure change required in my actual work.